# Surjections commuting with the function $t:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, $t(n) = n+1$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $t: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ be defined as $t(n) = n+1$. How many surjections $g:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ commute with $t$?

Is the following proof correct?

We require that $t(g(n)) = g(t(n))$ for every $n\geq 1$. Since 
$$g(t(n)) = g(n+1) \text{ and }\ t(g(n)) = g(n) + 1,$$
The condition $t(g(n)) = g(t(n))$ implies $g(n+1) = g(n) + 1$.

For $g$ to be a surjection, $g(1) = 1$: Otherwise, if $g(1) = m>1$, then $g(n) = m + n - 1$. Since $g$ is a surjection, there exists $k > 1$ such that $g(k) = m + k - 1 = 1$. So $m + k = 2$. This is a contradiction since $m,k > 1$, and so $m + k > 2$. Thus $g$ is not a surjection.

So $g(1) = 1$. Thus $g(n) = n$ for every $n \geq 1$. So the surjection is uniquely determined by the hypothesis.

So there is only one surjection commuting with $t$, namely the identity function.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(To kick this question away from the un-answered list): Yes, your proof is clear and correct.

Indeed you have shown the following: If $g$ commutes with $t$, then $g$ is of the form

$$g(n) = n+k$$
for some $k=0,1,2, \cdots$. So $g = t^k$ (composition of $t$'s).

Comment: Where k = 0 corresponds to the case where g is surjective?

Comment: Yes, @trynalearn